# Как переписать SQL-запрос в SQLite

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Пишу утилиту, которая замеряет расходы времени на выполнение разных задач
В SQLite всего две таблицы: Job & History

```
class Job(Base):
    """Выполняемые задачи"""
    __tablename__ = 'Job'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    command = Column(String(128))
    description = Column(String(128))

    def __init__(self, command: str, description: str):
        self.command = command
        self.description = description


class History(Base):
    """История выполняемых заданий"""
    __tablename__ = 'History'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer)
    job = Column(Integer)
    started = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    ended = Column(DateTime, default=None, nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, user_id: int, job: int):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.job = job
```

В конце дня идет вывод отчета за день: *сколько времени было потрачено на каждую задачу*.

Вычисления написал в SQL, а вот как этот же код оформить в SQLAlchemy догадываюсь смутно

```
SELECT j.description, sum((strftime('%s', h.ended) - strftime('%s', h.started)) / 60) as minutes
FROM History as h
INNER JOIN Job as j ON j.id = h.job
WHERE h.started >= date('now','-1 day')
GROUP BY job
ORDER BY minutes DESC
```

Comment: Получилось проверить?

Comment: @AndrewHolovko, не до конца, много основной работы. Я обязательно отмечу верный ответ, пока точно не знаю когда

Answer (score 1):

Так как Вы не используете внешний ключ для связи `History` с `Job` (`Foreign Key`):

```
with SessionContext() as session:
    query = session.query(Job)
    query = query.join(History, History.job == Job.id)
```

Если добавить - `job =  Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Job.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False, index=True)`, то ORM сам выполнит `INNER JOIN`:

```
with SessionContext() as session:
    query = session.query(Job, History)
```

сразу отфильтруем по дате

```
    query = query().filter(History.started >= datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

далее рассмотрим `group_by`, `sum` и `order_by`, попутно выбрав остальные поля.

```
 ...
   query = query(Job.description,
                (sqlalchemy.func.sum((sqlalchemy.func.strftime('%s', History.ended) -\
                                    sqlalchemy.func.strftime('%s', History.started))/60).label('minutes')\
                                                                  )\
                ).group_by(Job.id).order_by('minutes')
```

остается только собрать все во едино. Только не уверен, что к `minutes` можно будет так обратиться в сортировке, возможно будет требоваться корректировка. Как и не проверял работу функций для расчета времени.

Answer (score 0):

1. Название таблиц принято писать с маленькой буквы, снейк-кейсом.
2. В SQLAlchemy очень удобно строятся связи, я немного изменил ваш пример, суть вы поймёте. [Ссылку на документацию прикрепляю.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html)

```
class Job(Base):
    """Выполняемые задачи"""
    __tablename__ = 'job'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    command = Column(String(128))
    description = Column(String(128))
    history = relationship("History", back_populates="job")

    def __init__(self, command: str, description: str):
        self.command = command
        self.description = description


class History(Base):
    """История выполняемых заданий"""
    __tablename__ = 'history'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer)
    # job = Column(Integer)
    started = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    ended = Column(DateTime, default=None, nullable=True)
    job_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('job.id'))
    job = relationship("Job", back_populates="history")

    def __init__(self, user_id: int, job: int):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.job = job
```

**Отвечая на ваш вопрос:**

> В конце дня идет вывод отчета за день: сколько времени было потрачено на каждую задачу.
> Вычисления написал в SQL, а вот как этот же код оформить в SQLAlchemy догадываюсь смутно

Вы можете использовать инструкцию ниже. Она довольно простая. Ах да, вот и время затраченное по задаче.

```
>> from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
>> session = Session(engine)
>> db_job = session.query(models.Job).first()
>> print(sum([(i.started - i.ended).seconds//60 % 60 for i in db_job.history]))
177  # minutes
```

`db_job.history` - список объектов из БД, каждый имеет соответствующие поля